# how to use different mapview at same one mobile

Tags: android, google-maps

my  app is internationalization,so in some country have Fortress mobile phone,which is not have google Mapview,it not use mapactivity,so i cannot install my app to the  Fortress mobile phone. so myquestion:

1. if i can  add  common map.jar to my app,so i can use the jar to finish my app map effect ,not care  mapview in the Fortress mobile phone .i donot  know if  the seem common **map.jar**  is  exist at  present
2. if have other methods to meet my need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to determine, at runtime, whether GOogle Maps exists on the device, and take an alternative path if it does not.

1. you must build your app with Google Maps API, but set the required flag to "false" in your manifest

`<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required="false" />`

1. use code like this to determine if the library exists on the device

> try
>       {
>
> ```
>    mContext.getClassLoader().loadClass("com.google.android.maps.MapView");
>
>    // You have Google Maps
>
> }
>
> catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
>
> {   
>
>  // No Google Maps
>
> }
> ```

Comment: this is only my one problem,if not have google mapview, if my app also do other mapview. this increase my app big. if have other methods to compatible